# Where to start learning mandarin

Tags: mandarin, pinyin, learning, resources, books

I'm about to start learning mandarin chinese myself, without any teachers but with a help of textbooks and video (audio) lessons. My question is: where do I start, I mean, is it better to start with pinyin or with *Han characters*? What words do I need to start with? What about grammar?
Maybe someone can recommend me a good book to start with?

Comment: Ahhh they're not hieroglyphs!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Is it better now?

Comment: After you start learning, you can use this site as a sort of forum to ask for clarification or help!

Comment: Please see this: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding starting with pinyin or characters: [It's funny, I recently asked this question myself.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3806/teaching-pinyin-and-characters-together-vs-teaching-pinyin-then-characters) In your case, I would recommend:

- Starting with basics of pinyin... getting the hang of pronunciation. [TalkBank](http://talkbank.org/pinyin/Trad_chart.html) provides a pinyin chart that pronounces each for you given the selected tone. It's really cool. Just choose a tone, and click on a vowel/initial.
- Learn the 4 tones.

  Mā: 妈 = mother
  Má: 麻 = hemp
  Mǎ: 马 = horse
  Mà: 骂 = scold
- Start pairing characters with pinyin. Learn the basics/greetings.

  Nǐ hǎo: 你好 = hello
  Xièxiè：谢谢 = thank you
  Bù kèqì: 不客气 = you're welcome
  Zài jiàn: 再见 = good bye
- Solidify what you've learned by practicing in a chat room. I recommend [Zhongwen.com](http://zhongwen.com/) > then go to LiaoTian! (chat). Informal chat rooms were hugely helpful for me to get started.
- Once you have some basics of chatting down, maybe head over to a Chinese restaurant and try ordering in Chinese (most speak Mandarin or at least some Mandarin that I've encountered). Or find a local Chinese market, or anything... Anything for you to go and practice speaking Mandarin. This will get you comfortable speaking. But you need a foundation with the words first. So keep practicing them.
- For a book, Stumpy Joe recommended [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/7561910401). Also look at the [community wiki](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese) for Chinese learning resources.

Good luck! If I think of anything else I'll let ya know.

Comment: Your answer is just what I was asking for. Very thankful for book, chat room and TalkBank recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

Start with PinYin. Don't worry about writing and grammar at this stage. Find a native speaker to correct your tones. I have used chinese-bootcamp.com practice session several times, very useful to practice with native speakers.

Comment: Pinyin is difficult and illogical for people who don't already know Chinese. And it makes it easy to ignore tones until it's too late. I suspect learning through pinyin is a reason so few otherwise fluent foreigners have good tones.